# Hive startup -[ERROR] Terminal initialization failed; falling back to unsupported

Tags: java, hadoop, hive

I have downloaded hive and modified HADOOP_HOME to

```
HADOOP_HOME=${bin}/../../usr/local/hadoop
```

my actual hadoop path is

```
/usr/local/hadoop
```

in .bashrc i have added the below env variables

```
export HIVE_HOME=/usr/lib/hive/apache-hive-1.1.0-bin
export PATH=$PATH:$HIVE_HOME/bin
export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:/usr/local/Hadoop/lib/*:.
export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:/usr/local/hive/lib/*:.
```

then i tried starting hive using bin/hive. I got the below error

```
Logging initialized using configuration in jar:file:/usr/lib/hive/apache-hive-1.1.0-bin/lib/hive-common-1.1.0.jar!/hive-log4j.properties
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/lib/hive/apache-hive-1.1.0-bin/lib/hive-jdbc-1.1.0-standalone.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
[ERROR] Terminal initialization failed; falling back to unsupported
java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Found class jline.Terminal, but interface was expected
    at jline.TerminalFactory.create(TerminalFactory.java:101)
    at jline.TerminalFactory.get(TerminalFactory.java:158)
    at jline.console.ConsoleReader.<init>(ConsoleReader.java:229)
    at jline.console.ConsoleReader.<init>(ConsoleReader.java:221)
    at jline.console.ConsoleReader.<init>(ConsoleReader.java:209)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.getConsoleReader(CliDriver.java:773)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.executeDriver(CliDriver.java:715)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:675)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:615)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Found class jline.Terminal, but interface was expected
    at jline.console.ConsoleReader.<init>(ConsoleReader.java:230)
    at jline.console.ConsoleReader.<init>(ConsoleReader.java:221)
    at jline.console.ConsoleReader.<init>(ConsoleReader.java:209)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.getConsoleReader(CliDriver.java:773)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.executeDriver(CliDriver.java:715)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:675)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:615)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)
```

Answer (score 64, accepted):

I had the same problem and got it working from this link:

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Hive+on+Spark%3A+Getting+Started

- Hive has upgraded to Jline2 but jline 0.9x exists in the Hadoop lib.

So you should follow these steps:

1. Delete jline from the Hadoop lib directory (it's only pulled in transitively from ZooKeeper).
2. export HADOOP_USER_CLASSPATH_FIRST=true

Comment: This worked for me without even deleting jline jar, only HADOOP_USER_CLASSPATH_FIRST=true did the trick

Comment: Thanks but no need to delete the JAR from hadoop path.

Comment: Worked for me without deleting jar, it's not required.

Comment: Thanks much for this! Just setting additional env worked for me too.

Answer (score 9):

Try after removing the jline-0.9.94.jar file under the path $HADOOP_HOME/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jline-0.9.94.jar

Here's the link to jira ticket
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-8609

Answer (score 5):

I just set the

```
HADOOP_USER_CLASSPATH_FIRST=true
```

and it works for me for this issue.

Answer (score 4):

Try to delete one of this file

SLF4J: Found binding in [**jar:file:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class**]

SLF4J: Found binding in [**jar:file:/usr/lib/hive/apache-hive-1.1.0-bin/lib/hive-jdbc-1.1.0-standalone.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class**]

then i think it will only choose to bind to one. so multiple binding will not be available anymore

Comment: All the errors related to SLF4J are gone!!!Your answer took me half the way, But I am still stuck with the java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError. Do you have any idea what exactly it is?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with cloudera CDH5.4 . Removing jline-0.9.94.jar from yarn/libs folder worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Do this `locate jline`.

The file, jline-0.9.94.jar, is located in 3 locations, delete it from all the 3 locations and do the necessary export:

```
$ export HADOOP_USER_CLASSPATH_FIRST=true
```

Comment: no need to delete the jline-0.9.94.jar library instead of that you just add  "export HADOOP_USER_CLASSPATH_FIRST=true" in bashrc

Answer (score 1):

With  Hadoop version 2.4.1 and Hive 1.2.0. I had the same issue. And after setting HADOOP_USER_CLASSPATH_FIRST=true in .bashrc

It worked like a charm!!!

Answer (score 0):

check this link it might help you [Facing issue while running hive from CLI](https://frustrateddevelopers.blogspot.com/b/post-preview?token=7PtoJFABAAA.ZB-Dc9NljrOaddeg1Vk8sbUSXygmHHMGFqBd2k4u5Ed39cLJXQYynqsWcGzbkbLTGz1W5vW9LEQ20fybw4s9OA.XdOr-XtwW_wklpK8zFmH0g&postId=2472583767358407952&type=POST)

Answer (score 0):

With the new version of Hive (1.2.1), I just had to replace jline-2.12.jar with jline-2.13.jar in the installation / lib folder.

Answer (score 0):

You should init the hadoop libary:

```
$ vi ~/.bashrc
$ export HADOOP_USER_CLASSPATH_FIRST=true
$ source .bashrc
$ hive
```

Answer (score 0):

I renamed

`addJava "-Djline.terminal=jline.UnixTerminal"`

to

`addJava "-Djline.terminal=jline2.UnixTerminal"`

in the "activator" file