# Error starting PIG: ERROR 2998: Unhandled internal error. Found interface jline.Terminal, but class was expected

Tags: apache-pig

I downloaded Pig from apache, I have installed it, tried to run it using `pig -x local`

This is what I get:

```
    15/12/10 15:06:26 INFO pig.ExecTypeProvider: Trying ExecType : LOCAL
15/12/10 15:06:26 INFO pig.ExecTypeProvider: Trying ExecType : MAPREDUCE
15/12/10 15:06:26 INFO pig.ExecTypeProvider: Picked MAPREDUCE as the ExecType
2015-12-10 15:06:26,063 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.Main - Apache Pig version 0.15.0 (r1682971) compiled Jun 01 2015, 11:44:35
2015-12-10 15:06:26,063 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.Main - Logging error messages to: /usr/local/pig/pig_1449756386061.log
2015-12-10 15:06:26,097 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.impl.util.Utils - Default bootup file /home/ubuntu/.pigbootup not found
2015-12-10 15:06:26,132 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.Main - ERROR 2998: Unhandled internal error. Found interface jline.Terminal, but class was expected
Details at logfile: /usr/local/pig/pig_1449756386061.log
2015-12-10 15:06:26,157 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.Main - Pig script completed in 206 milliseconds (206 ms)
```

My log file contains the following:

```
Error before Pig is launched
----------------------------
ERROR 2998: Unhandled internal error. Found interface jline.Terminal, but class was expected

java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Found interface jline.Terminal, but class was expected
    at jline.ConsoleReader.<init>(ConsoleReader.java:174)
    at jline.ConsoleReader.<init>(ConsoleReader.java:169)
    at org.apache.pig.Main.run(Main.java:556)
    at org.apache.pig.Main.main(Main.java:177)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)
================================================================================
```

After I downloaded and extracted the package, I did the following (pig is in /usr/local/pig):

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_79
  196  export PIG_PREFIX=/usr/local/pig
  197  export PATH=$PATH:$PIG_PREFIX/bin
```

Any ideas what is wrong?

Thanks,
Serban

Answer (score 7):

Add this -

```
export HADOOP_USER_CLASSPATH_FIRST=true
```

Refer
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PIG-3851
[hive startup -[ERROR] Terminal initialization failed; falling back to unsupported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28997441/hive-startup-error-terminal-initialization-failed-falling-back-to-unsupporte)